# Python: How can I concatenate images horizontally without OpenCV?

Tags: python

I'm generating a waveform with matplotlib for a video to display in a webpage. However, due to the required image size and the length of the video, I get an error because the image is too big and can't be generated, so I am now creating several smaller images for the waveform.

What I'd like to do now is to concatenate all these images horizontally to then show them in the webpage. I think this is easier than sending 30+ images in the response and then showing them side by side. I have only found how to do this with OpenCV, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it without it so I don't have to install a whole AI package/library only to do this.

Comment: You could do it with ImageMagick (very easily), which is installed on Linux and can be installed on Windows or Mac OSX. If you need a Python package, then perhaps try Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick. In ImageMagick it is -append. In Python Wand it is called concat.

Comment: Great. I'll try those and update.